# Bootstrap Carousel that Shows 3(or more) items on browsers and just 1 on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to ask about bootstrap carousel.

I need to show 3 logos scrolling on desktop and if on mobile, it will be just 1 per scroll.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<a class="item"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
<a class="item"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
<a class="item"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
<a class="item"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

[This is a drawing of what is needed, mobile shows 1 image, desktop 3 images / carousel item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdgYx.jpg)

Comment: Did you see some JavaScript error on mobile?

Comment: I don't see any. I am sorry, I just wanted this tagged for bootstrap, I do not think that there is a need to check/modify/add a js

Answer (score 0):

Simple use bootstrap hidden class to hide other images for mobile

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<a class="item"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
<a class="hidden-xs item"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
<a class="hidden-xs item"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
<a class="hidden-xs item"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```